# SQL syntax to update my Date Dimension table with calendar year codes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, casting

I have a Date Dimension table which contains every single date from Year 2000 to Year 2018. I need to add a new column to my Date Dimension which will be called `'CY'`.

I need column `'CY`' to be filled with the following codes:

If date is between, say, `01 January 2015 to 31 December 2015`, then the code will be `'CY 2015'` and so on. I also have a column called Year and its datatype is `'int'`.

I'm stuck at this point:

```
USE MyDatabase
UPDATE DateDimension
SET CY = 'CY' + ' ' + cast(Year AS text)
```

I am getting this error msg:

> "Explicit conversion from data type int to text is not allowed."

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE DateDimension
SET CY = 'CY ' + cast([Year] AS NVARCHAR(4));
```

or if **`SQL Server 2012+`**:

```
UPDATE DateDimension
SET CY = CONCAT('CY ', [Year]);
```

Probably the best way is to use computed column (no need to manual update):

```
ALTER TABLE DateDimension
ADD CY AS CONCAT('CY ', [Year]);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/395132)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
alter table DateDimension
add CY as 'CY'+ ' ' + left (Year, 4)
```